# Is it possible to add an online value to my code and it changes automatically? like dollar value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web, mongoose

I'm making a shopping website and my client requested me (I'm still a practitioner) if it's possible to make the prices changes automatically according to iron ups and downs. So he has no to change it manually. If so is there a tutorial or guide you can recommend to me? I work with node js and MongoDB.

Comment: On what basis, prices should be changed?

Comment: depending on the ups and downs of the iron value.

Comment: It's not that easy, depends on the use case, if you're taking price from other source then you can update those prices into the database by running a cron job at wanted interval. There is another approach in AI, called price optimization algorithm which changes the prices dynamically based on the demand and supply. So, it totally depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use https://metals-api.com/ to get the current price every time someone consults the web.

If you want to avoid exhaustive calls to this API, you could create a process in MongoDB or in NodeJS which get the data from this API and save it in database every 5 seconds